How can I make calculations on Interactive grid column for all rows automatically?
I have entry from users they enter the values of
RESULT , MEAN AND SD
In my side I need to calculate the SDI value and I created dynamic action to calculate SDI
this is the code :
var mean = ($v("C_MEAN") != "")?parseFloat($v("C_MEAN")):0;
var sd = ($v("C_SD") != "")?parseFloat($v("C_SD")):0;
var result = ($v("C_RESULT") != "")?parseFloat($v("C_RESULT")):0;
var sdi = 0;

if(!isNaN(mean) && !isNaN(sd) && !isNaN(result) ) 
{
    sdi = (result - mean) / sd;
}
$s("C_SDI",sdi);

Whan I select the data it show all rows with result , mean and SD
like this image :

can I run the java script code to calculate direct the SDI column values for all rows automatically
when the grid select the data ?
UPDATE :
this is the SQL query I did it in SQL but when I save it show error
ORA-01733: virtual column not allowed here


select id_no,
       TESTID, 
       UNITID , 
       result,
       MEAN,
       SD,
       (result-mean)/sd as "SDI",
         LOW_LIMIT,
         HIGH_LIMIT,
         PERF_ID
         FROM HAJJ_QC_RESULTS 
         where sample_id = :P13_SAMPLE
         and program_id = :P13_PROGRAM
         and machine_id = :P13_MACHINE
         and hospital_no = :P13_HOSPITAL
         and approved_date = :P13_FROMDATE


I would do that in the query. Gives best performance and your rows won't be marked as updated.

@KarelEkema I did the calculation in SQL but how to save to SDI column when click save button in grid it show error ORA-01733: virtual column not allowed here

Yeah, I should have mentioned - in the column definition of SDI, section 'Source', you can  check 'Query Only' for this one.

@KarelEkema but how can I copy the value and update the database with actual SDI value can I copy the value from virtual SDI column to the real SDI database column , for example create button and when click on button copy the same values from virtual SDI column to the SDI database column then click save button after make a copy ?

I found the solution
to copy the column data I created page button and then created dynamic action
and execute the following java script code :
var widget = apex.region('validate').widget();
var grid = widget.interactiveGrid('getViews','grid');
var model = grid.model;

model.forEach(function (r) {

model.setValue(r , "SDI" , model.getValue(r ,"SDIT"));

})

by using this code I will create a loop in this loop I will set the value of column SDI and get it from the column SDIT then when click the button it will copy column data from SDIT to SDI column
